# Отключить TRACE библиотеке

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

Отключаю Define TRACE constant в вкладке Build для моего приложения. Но библиотека продолжает трассировку в консоли. Как можно отключить трассировку для библиотеки. Пробовал запускать Release, собирал самостоятельно исходник библиотеки - не помогло

Comment: "Как можно отключить трассировку для библиотеки" - зависит от библиотеки. Вы б название её что ли написали... а то на телепатов надежды мало.

Comment: Я вижу в исходинке следующий код
#if TRACE
Так вот когда я снимаю галочку c TRACE.Упорно заходит в эти блоки. Библиотека - DokanNet